# How can I substitute a greek l for the lambda keyword in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I recently saw David Beazley's talk at Pycon 2019 where he discussed lambda calculus.  One thing he did was to be able to directly insert a greek lambda symbol and the editor would substitute that with the lambda keyword in Python.

I've tried using Google to see if this is possible in the Jupyter notebook but haven't found a way to do it.

Is there an notebook extension or plugin floating around somewhere that can do this?

Thanks

Comment: I find it harder to type the greek lambda symbol then the word `lambda`.

Comment: Possibly, but I can extend this question to be:  How can I substitute a python statement with a single letter and have the editor automatically substitute it. I think that might be kind of a useful shortcut.

Comment: yeah, I see that

Comment: Go to "help/edit keyboard shortcuts"